# Does a bread box requires holes for ventilation?

Tags: bread, storage

I am trying to figure out whether a breadbox should have ventilation holes or not. There are many for sale with and without. When I look at most breadbox pictures, going from vintage to modern, I don't see holes, but some contemporary ones have holes. I understand bread produces moisture and it's important to let it out?

Answer (score 4):

There is no one true answer to it - otherwise you would see only one style of bread box. The better the ventilation, the faster the bread becomes hard and the less likely it is for the bread to develop mold - and vice versa, the less ventilation, the longer the bread does stay soft, the more likely it is to develop mold.